# Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /home/ec2-user/public_html/cgi-bin/

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

When I tried to access the `http://host-ip/~ec2-user/cgi-bin/try.cgi`, I got `403 Forbidden` error, `error_log` shows `Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /home/ec2-user/public_html/cgi-bin/try.cgi`. If I commented out `AddHandler` line, I can see the script text, though. Below is some basic information. Do you have any clue what is preventing the server from parsing CGI scripts? Thanks!

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-245-79-145 cgi-bin]$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-245-79-145 3.4.37-40.44.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 21 01:17:08 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[ec2-user@ip-10-245-79-145 cgi-bin]$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr 30 2013 22:53:39

[ec2-user@ip-10-245-79-145 cgi-bin]$ tail /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/public_html/cgi-bin/">
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

No `.htaccess` file in the `/home/ec2-user/public_html/cgi-bin/` directory, no `SELinux` running, `suexec.log` shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the reason after reading [how sections are merged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin), my script works after commenting out the following lines in my httpd.conf:

```
<Location />
       Options         Includes
       AddHandler      server-parsed .shtml
</Location>
```